# sql query change dimensional table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table : this is same with log for user login frequency

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦═════════════╗
║ month-year ║ user  ║ count_login ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║ 01-2016    ║ admin ║          12 ║
║ 01-2016    ║ user1 ║          10 ║
║ 02-2016    ║ admin ║           5 ║
║ 03-2016    ║ admin ║          15 ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═════════════╝
```

its possiblly change to

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ month-year ║ admin ║ user1 ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ 01-2016    ║    12 ║    10 ║
║ 02-2016    ║     5 ║     0 ║
║ 03-2016    ║    15 ║     0 ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

if possible, what query can i use??

Comment: Hint:  `group by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to do this

```
select `month-year`, 
       sum(case when user = 'admin' then count_login else 0 end) as admin,
       sum(case when user = 'user1' then count_login else 0 end) as user1
From yourtable
Group by `month-year`
```

Check this answer for dynamic pivoting : [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: how if use a dynamical coloumn, that user may can be more than that user, may be user2, user3, ect.

Comment: Updated my answer with link